# Call multiple stored procedures in foreach Azure Pipeline Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

My requirement is to call multiple stored procedures in Data Factory Pipeline, using lookup activity. I'm executing a Select query which list me the total stored procedure names in a json format as shown below:

[image]

```
  {
        "count": 4,
        "value": [
            {
                "ProcedureName": "DimAccount"
            },
            {
                "ProcedureName": "DimAct"
            },
            {
                "ProcedureName": "DimActivity"
            },
            {
                "ProcedureName": "DimyType"
            }
        ],
        "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (West US)",
        "billingReference": {
            "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
            "billableDuration": [
                {
                    "meterType": "ManagedVNetIR",
                    "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                    "unit": "DIUHours"
                }
            ]
        },
        "durationInQueue": {
            "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
        }
    }
```

After this I added a ForEach activity and then inside foreach I added an append activity to get all stored procedure names in a separate variable called `spName` declared as variable `Array` parameter at outer canvas of the pipeline. During the execution of the pipeline I see appendactivity variable gets holds the Individual record as below

[image]

```
{
    "variableName": "spName",
    "value": "DimyType"
}
```

so on

```
{
        "variableName": "spName",
        "value": "DimAccount"
}
```

Similarly for other values too with all 4 append activity holds an individual array values, I added a stored procedure activity and trying to call the with below expression from appendactivity

[image]

```
  @string(item().ProcedureName)
```

[image]

From my Append activity I need to extract only the stored procedure name out of the json i.e

```
"value": "DimAct"
```

and pass it to stored procedure activity as "DimAct" stored procedure name

Instead I see again whole json pull to stored procedure Activity as below

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": {
        "ProcedureName": "DimAct"
    }
}
```

Due to this I see error in the stored procedure activity

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated, I'm quite new to Azure environment I found Append Variable activity could be a good match for this requirement, I may be wrong any other activity or approach to achieve my goal with new suggestions are also welcome

Comment: no need to use append activity. just pass lookup output to foreach by `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` and then create stored procedure activity in it and give dynamic value as `@item().SPECIFIC_NAME` it will run all the stored procedures. [see here](https://i.imgur.com/UJHqeWt.png)

Comment: Thanks for your response!If you don't mind, can you reshare your solution I cannot see images here

Comment: I updated the answer please let me know it is visible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tried to reproduce similar issue and got same error**

[image]

> The issue is causing due to append variable append the values into array and then it is passing that array to stored procedure.

- **Solution**
  **My sample output of Lookup Activity**

[image]

**There is no need to use append activity**. just pass lookup output to foreach by `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

Then create stored procedure activity in it and give dynamic value as `@item().SPECIFIC_NAME` it will run all the stored procedures.

[image]

**Pipeline executed successfully**

[image]